# What is the best way to show contract data on a website

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

The data needed to be available through the website is a list of links (1000+), which may be updated (or not) at the rate of 100 links a day. And a list of usernames which starts from 0 and new users may be appended to the list at the rate of say 10 000 a day.

As far as I understand the contract needs to fire events everytime a change is made. But the rest I can't understand)).

Is there a very light php or python "web-server-side" ethereum client which doesn't need to download chaindata?
Or do I need to use some blockchain explorer API to get information?
Or I better send updates to website DB from my local machine (win 8.1)?

What is the simpliest reliable solution here?

Comment: Found several projects using Meteor. Could anybody please confirm it can solve my problem? (I just cannot understand from the description it gives).

Comment: Others use socket.io - a web socket. Could anybody explain the difference between using web socket and meteor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your system stores data on the blockchain, your platform will likely need a full set of chaindata to operate. You can use a light wallet that downloads portions of the blockchain from a trusted source, those are designed for clients or iot where resources are tight, and security can be delegated to a trusted source.

If the system you're designing relies on ethereum (or any blockchain), your platform architecture should likely include a full node and using web3 (or appropriate) to communicate with the node.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Yes, the recources are very tight)). Is there a light wallet able to download only a specific contract data? Would you please recomend the exact services or cliens. 

Is it a good way to pull data from blockchain by some client and then send it to website db?